# Python: Scraping Amazon webpage with bs4, BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to read specific information(name, price, etc. ...) from an Amazon webpage.
For that I'm using "BeautifulSoup" & "requests" as suggested in most tutorials. My code can load the page and find the item I'm looking for but fails to actually get it. I checked the webpage the item definetly exists.

Here is my code:

```
#import time
import requests
#import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = ('https://www.amazon.de/dp/B008JCUXNK/?coliid=I9G2T92PZXG06&colid=3ESRXLK53S0NY&psc=1&ref_=lv_ov_lig_dp_it')

# user agent = browser information (get via google search "my user agent")
headers = {"User-Agent": 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:80.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/80.0'}

page = requests.get(URL, headers=headers)# webpage

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')# webpage as html

title = soup.find(id="productTitle")


print(title)
```

title is always "NONE" so calling get_Text will cause an error.
Can anybody tell me what's wrong?

Comment: The data might be dynamically loaded through JavaScript. You get the response but Js has not yet done loading the data. Just use https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-splash or any other framework that waits for both page and JavaScript to load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is 100% correct, but I've tried your code and checked value of `page.content`. It contains captcha. Looks like Amazon don't want you to scrape their site.

You can read about your case here: https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/bf21fn/how_to_prevent_captcha_while_scraping_amazon/.

But I also recommend to read Amazon's Terms And Conditions https://www.amazon.com/gp/help/customer/display.html/ref=hp_551434_conditions to be sure if you can legally scrape it.

Comment: Thanks for the quick anwser mate. It makes sense that Amazon would do that. I checked the link u sent me but even with the advanced header I'm not getting the information. But that should be possible somehow. After all I can access the webpage with my browser. Do u know of any way around that captcha?

Answer (score 2):

Found a way to get past the captcha.
The request needs to contain a better header.
Example:

```
import datetime    
import requests

KEY = "YOUR_KEY_HERE"
date = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d")

BASE_REQUEST = ('https://www.amazon.de/Philips-Haartrockner-ThermoProtect-Technologie-HP8230/dp/B00BCQIIMS?pf_rd_r=T1T8Z7QTQTGYM8F7KRN5&pf_rd_p=c832d309-197e-4c59-8cad-735a8deab917&pd_rd_r=20c6ed33-d548-47d7-a262-c53afe32df96&pd_rd_w=63hR3&pd_rd_wg=TYwZH&ref_=pd_gw_crs_zg_bs_84230031')

headers = {
    'dnt': '1',
    'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.61 Safari/537.36',
    'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
    'sec-fetch-site': 'same-origin',
    'sec-fetch-mode': 'navigate',
    'sec-fetch-user': '?1',
    'sec-fetch-dest': 'document',
    'referer': 'https://www.amazon.com/',
    'accept-language': 'en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8',
}

payload = {
    "api-key": KEY,
    "begin_date": date,
    "end_date": date,
    "q": "Donald Trump"
}

r = requests.get(BASE_REQUEST, headers=headers)

print(r.status_code)

if r.status_code == 200:
    print('success')
```

For information on status codes just google html status codes.
Hope this helps anyone with similar problems

Cheers!